# multinomial logistic regression in R: multinom in nnet package result different from mlogit in mlogit package?

Tags: r, mlogit

Both R functions, `multinom` (package `nnet`) and `mlogit` (package `mlogit`) can be used for multinomial logistic regression. But why this example returns different result of p values of coefficients?

**`#prepare data`**

```
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
mydata$gre[1:10] = rnorm(10,mean=80000)
```

**`#multinom`:**

```
test = multinom(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata)
z <- summary(test)$coefficients/summary(test)$standard.errors
# For simplicity, use z-test to approximate t test.
pv <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z)))*2 
pv
# (Intercept)         gre         gpa       rank2       rank3       rank4 
# 0.00000000  0.04640089  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
```

**`#mlogit`:**

```
mldata = mlogit.data(mydata,choice = 'admit', shape = "wide")

mlogit.model1 <- mlogit(admit ~ 1 | gre + gpa + rank, data = mldata)
summary(mlogit.model1)
# Coefficients :
#   Estimate  Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
# 1:(intercept) -3.5826e+00  1.1135e+00 -3.2175 0.0012930 ** 
#   1:gre          1.7353e-05  8.7528e-06  1.9825 0.0474225 *  
#   1:gpa          1.0727e+00  3.1371e-01  3.4195 0.0006274 ***
#   1:rank2       -6.7122e-01  3.1574e-01 -2.1258 0.0335180 *  
#   1:rank3       -1.4014e+00  3.4435e-01 -4.0697 4.707e-05 ***
#   1:rank4       -1.6066e+00  4.1749e-01 -3.8482 0.0001190 ***
```

Why the p values from `multinorm` and `mlogit` are so different? I guess it is because of the outliers I added using `mydata$gre[1:10] = rnorm(10,mean=80000)`. If outlier is an inevitable issue (for example in genomics, metabolomics, etc.), which R function should I use?

Comment: Why are you estimating a multinomial model when the response is dichotomous? If you estimate a simple logistic GLM, you get the same result as `mlogit`: `summary(glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family=binomial))`.

Comment: hi @JasonMorgan, to my understanding, multinomial logistic regression is an extension of bionomial logistic regression. Thus it should work to use multinomial procedure to deal with dichotomous dependent variable. In this question, I aim to find out the reason why two R functions for multinomial procedures gives two different result, using a same set of samples (although the samples have a dichotomous outcome).

Comment: If you scale your data, as suggested by the `nnet` function, you get the same standard errors.

Comment: TRUE! I didn't notice it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference here is the difference between the Wald $z$ test (what you calculated in  `pv`)  and the Likelihood Ratio test (what is returned by `summary(mlogit.model)`. The Wald test is computationally simpler, but in general has less desirable properties (e.g., its CIs are not scale-invariant). You can read more about the two procedures [here](http://thestatsgeek.com/2014/02/08/wald-vs-likelihood-ratio-test/).

To perform LR tests on your `nnet` model coefficents, you can load the `car` and `lmtest` packages and call `Anova(test)` (though you'll have to do a little more work for the single df tests).

Comment: Nice reference! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As alternative, you can use `broom`, which outputs tidy format for `multinom` class models.

```
library(broom)

tidy(test)
```

It'll return a `data.frame` with z-statistics and p-values. 
Take a look at [`tidy`](https://broom.tidyverse.org/reference/tidy.multinom.html) documentation for further information.

---

*P.S.: as I can't get the data from the link you posted, I can't replicate the results*